# Создание несколько гугл карт через цикл

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps

Вот HTML

```
<div class="slide_map" id="map_sl_1" data-lat= "50.4488889" data-lat= "30.5295878" data-zoom = "16"></div>
<div class="slide_map" id="map_sl_2" data-lat= "51.4488889" data-lat= "31.5295878" data-zoom = "10"></div>
```

Вот JS

```
function mapCreate(id, latval, lngval, z) {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
    center: {lat: latval, lng: lngval},
    scrollwheel: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    zoom: z,
    styles: styles
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: latval, lng: lngval},
    title: ''
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slide_map").each(function() {
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        latval = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-lat"));
        lngval = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-lat"));
        z = parseInt($(this).attr("data-zoom"));
        mapCreate(id, latval, lngval, z);
    });
});
```

Браузер пишет ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at mapCreate
```

Как можно создать Google карту через цикл?

Comment: А вы у себя подключили google API?

Comment: Да подключил)))

Comment: Я так понимаю если вы все подключали по документации, то скорее всего у вас в подключение есть слово async? Можете попробывать переместить функцию mapCreate() в event ready или попробуйте убрать слово async в подключаемой API, отпиши если что-то из этого сработало.

Comment: Добавлю возьмите ссылку подключение и просто вставте ее в поисковую строку, у вас там ошибок 4** 5** нету

Comment: Убрал слово async карта появилась, но пока что на первой карте картинка карты появилась а на второй нет еще.

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось сделать вот так

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        mapCreate("map_sl_1", 50.4488889, 30.5295878, 15);
        mapCreate("map_sl_2", 50.4488889, 30.5295888, 15);
        mapCreate("map_sl_3", 50.4488889, 30.5295868, 15);
        mapCreate("map_sl_4", 50.4488889, 30.5295898, 15);
    });
</script>
```